# Dollar sign and/or Dash breaking Razor's parser

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

the end-result i'm trying to render:

```
<input type="radio" name="options" id="options_1" />$1 - A Not Very Expensive Chocolate
<input type="radio" name="options" id="options_2" />$10 - A Kinda Expensive Chocolate
<input type="radio" name="options" id="options_3" />$100 - A Really Expensive Chocolate
```

From this code:

```
@foreach (var o in Model.Options){
    <input type="radio" name="options" id=@("options_" + @o.ID) />$@o.PriceToAdd - @o.Label
}
```

If i drop both the '$' and the '-' from what should be plain old text - stuff works. Adding either resulted in compiler warnings and runtime errors. I've tried the [explicit syntax as described here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx) but haven't found the right combination yet.

Comment: Not to quibble with the added mvc-3 tag... isn't Razor applicable to .net 4 web forms too?

Comment: And ASP.NET Web Pages/WebMatrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
@foreach (var o in Model.Options) {
    <input type="radio" name="options" id=@("options_" + @o.ID) />
    <text>$</text>@o.PriceToAdd - @o.Label
}
```

or:

```
@foreach (var o in Model.Options) {
    <input type="radio" name="options" id=@("options_" + @o.ID) />
    @:$@o.PriceToAdd - @o.Label
}
```

or:

```
@foreach (var o in Model.Options) {
    <input type="radio" name="options" id=@("options_" + @o.ID) />
    @MvcHtmlString.Create("$")@o.PriceToAdd - @o.Label
}
```

or if `PriceToAdd` is numeric:

```
@foreach (var o in Model.Options) {
    <input type="radio" name="options" id=@("options_" + @o.ID) />
    @o.PriceToAdd.ToString("c") - @o.Label
}
```

Comment: 1st option still blew on the dash. 2nd worked ... thank goodness cuz the others made me wish for <%= theOldDays. %> ;)

Comment: or <text>$</text> and <text> - </text>