# VS 11 Beta - possible Razor bug

Tags: razor

I've found what appears to be a strangeness in VS 11 Beta Views regarding how Javascript is parsed and handled in Views. I've boiled it down to the smallest possible example to show the problem.

```
@section tester {
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function Something(direction) {

        if (direction == "-") {

        } else if (direction == "+") {

        } else {    // direction = "" or anything else
            for (var idx = 0; idx < forms.length; idx++) {
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
}
```

This looks to me like it should be a valid (although meaningless) definition of a section which does something, however, VS11Beta doesn't recognise it as a complete section for me. The final closing brace is not coloured yellow, and it reports a build error.

Removing any one of the JS sections (brace to brace) makes it work (the closing brace is coloured, etc.)

Can anyone repeat this, or is it just me? I don't need a workaround, just some confirmation that this is actually a bug, and not something stupid at my end.

Thanks!

Comment: Someone who looking for [temporary solution - see here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562192/dollar-sign-and-or-dash-breaking-razors-parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was confirmed as a bug by Microsoft, will be fixed in the next release.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/736777/vs-11-beta-possible-razor-parser-bug